# How to delete an array element that has an index in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The document looks like this,

```
{
"_id":"ffffff999999999f9ff9f9f9f",
 "Name" : "John Doe",
  "Array" : [{
      "Id1" : "a8ed3d86b8464e0cae4672cef3862860",
      "Id2" : "6d7aac14b1e142abafde167d928e3dbc",
      "Id3" : "2323232"
    }]
}
```

There is a uniqueness index on the combination of the 3 array elements.
So the index looks like this,

```
        "key" : {
                "Array.Id1" : 1,
                "Array.Id2" : 1,
                "Array.Id3" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
```

My requirement: I would like to find documents based on "_id" value and remove the array element completely.

Problem: 
I was trying something like this,

```
db.Collection.update({"_id":"ffffffff52a8a15ce4b05d6a8d40f973"},{$unset:{Array:1}})
```

When i try to unset the array element, the first update goes through but the consecutive ones fail with the following error,

***E11000 duplicate key error index: int.Collection.$Array.Id1_1_Array.Id2_1_Array.Id3_1  dup key: { : null, : null, : null }***

I am wondering if there is any work around for this issue.

I would have to run this on a huge collection and modifying the indexes is not an option.

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to modify or remove the index.

Answer (score 1):

Unique indexes work that way. You cannot have duplicates on the indexed fields even null values(or leave it undefined).
However the `sparse` option allows you to achieve this.

Usage: `db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true } )`

So if you are going to `unset` the array, you might want to re-index with the sparse option.

```
Warning: Using these indexes will sometimes result in incomplete results 
when filtering or sorting results, because sparse indexes are not complete 
for all documents in a collection.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. since re-indexing is not an option for me. i would try to set the value to something else(some dummy unique value) during the update.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated in this minimal example, it is not possible to have a unique-indexed field unset more than once right from the start - the problem not only occurs when you try to unset it later on.

```
> db.coll.ensureIndex({indexField:1}, {unique: true})
> db.coll.insert({name: "doc without index field 1"})
> db.coll.insert({name: "doc without index field 2"})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.coll.$indexField_1  dup key: { : null }
```

You will have to replace the field with something else - not necessarily an array, but it will have to be unique...

Comment: You can use `sparse` as shown in the other answer to allow unset values.